# SQL Server Management Studio keeping connection open

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I've run into a situation as a DBA where SSMS (not sure of the version) is keeping ad-hoc connections open and causing blocking. The only way to release the ad-hoc connections is to have the user running the ad-hoc queries to shut down their SSMS. When they do that, I can see in the activity monitor, that the connection is finally closed.

Is there a way to close these connections without closing SSMS or running a KILL SESSION command?

Comment: Close the query windows, not SSMS. Each query window uses a connection. Blocking is caused due to transactions that were left open, not the connection itself

Comment: You also need to disconnect from the server in Object Explorer, which maintains one open connection per server.

Comment: There's no reason to disconnect from Object Explorer. In fact, even closing a window isn't needed *unless* there's an active transaction left open which keeps rows locked. Object Explorer *and* Activity Monitor only query system tables and views

Comment: `have the user running the ad-hoc queries to shut down their SSMS.` SSMS is a tool for developers and DBAs, not users. If other DBAs or developers leave transactions (not just connections) open, they *should* terminate them.

Comment: Why are users using SSMS at all? Why not eg Excel with Power Query or Power BI? These applications are built for data analysis explicitly and usually don't even need a connection after the initial load. Power BI is free but includes the same analytic engine as SSAS.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If users are leaving open database transactions then the *user* should be terminated.

Comment: you must find a problem session.SSMS is a one of tools for developers and DBAs ,you can use sqlcmd for run query and dbforge Tools or DBeaver Tools

Comment: @abolfazlsadeghi all of these tools work the same way - one query window/script, one connection. It's the developer's/DBA's job to make sure they commit/rollback transactions and close connections that are no longer needed.